# FIR filter design

Tags: filters, filter-design

I am designing an FIR filter.my specs are fs=300MHz, Fc=45MHz, Fs=75MHz, passband gain=3dB , stopband attn=>40dB. what parameters I values of *a* have to provide in *firpm* for the minimum order filter design. 
I am putting *a=[0.01 0.01]*. is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want a low pass filter. Such a filter has one passband and one stopband, and accordingly you need an `a` vector with 4 elements:

1. the desired magnitude at frequency $0$
2. the desired magnitude at the passband edge ($f_c$)
3. the desired magnitude at the stopband edge ($f_s$)
4. the desired magnitude at Nyquist

If I understood your specs correctly, you should use `a = [sqrt(2) sqrt(2) 0 0]`, and your `f` vector is `f = [0 0.3 0.5 1]` because you need to normalize $f_c$ and $f_s$ by the Nyquist frequency $f_s/2=150$MHz. I would suggest you just try some values of `n` until you reach the desired stopband attenuation. Since you didn't specify any maximum passband ripple, the response in the passband will be fine anyway. If not, you can add a weight vector to trade off maximum passband ripple with stopband attenuation. See the [MathWorks documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/signal/ref/firpm.html) on how to do this.

Comment: the passband gain is mentioned but passband ripple is not mentioned in the problem. How can I decide the passband ripple?

Comment: I am using dev=[0.01 0.01] (not a=[0.01 0.01], done mistake in question)

Comment: I am using a=[1.41 1.41 0 0]. for 40dB attenuation in stopband, deviation shouldn't be 0.01?

Comment: @JayeshP: No, because you're approximating the desired value of zero in the stopband. The filter will have ripples in the stopband the maximum amplitude of which will end up being 40dB (after you've found the necessary filter order).

Comment: okay. what about a=[1.41 1.41 0.01 0.01] ?

Comment: @JayeshP: That's what I've tried to explain in my previous comment. If you try to approxinmate -40dB you'll always have an approximation error and end up with an attenuation smaller than the desired -40dB. Just try it yourself.

Comment: thanx for the help matt.

Comment: what does w define? should it be kept [1 1] or can be changed?

Comment: @JayeshP It's the weight vector I mentioned in my answer. If you were to choose e.g. `w=[1 10]` then you would weigh the stopband error 10 times as much as the passband error, i.e the stopband error would be 10 times smaller than the passband error.